# How to style all elements that share data attribute values?

Tags: html, css

I have a generic table on my hands to which I've added a data attribute index with a value:

```
<table>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Would it be possible to influence all elements who share the same value of data-index through css?

Something like - CSS:

```
td[data-index.value]:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is that when I hover over one td element all the other td elements who share the data-index value (example all who are ="1") get styliside. I am trying to accomplish a vertical column highlight.

Sollution that relies on javascript (typescript) and react:

The way I solved it with react and typescript if someone finds this later:

```
const handleColumnHoverEnter = (e: any) => {
    const allWithAttribute = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll("[data-index='" + e.target.dataset.index + "']")
      );
      allWithAttribute.forEach((element:any) => {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });
  }

  const handleColumnHoverLeave = (e: any) => {
    const allWithAttribute = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll("[data-index='" + e.target.dataset.index + "']")
      );
      allWithAttribute.forEach((element:any) => {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      });
  }
```

Thanks to users **bloodyKnucklese**'s and **t.niese**'s suggestions!

Comment: In your example the indices are simply the column number. You would be able to style that by means of `:nth-child`. Is that your case or might these indices have different numbers?

Comment: Is it okay to use Javascript?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with just CSS, since you can't traverse up the structure with CSS, a hovered element could never style elements that come "above" it.

Comment: Yes javascript is ok! I'm actually using react but wanted to see if there was a low level solution with just html and css, wanted to avoid over-engineering a solution so I thought I'd check if I missed something with data attributes first

Comment: Don't add your own solution to the question. Use the answer section instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript to add [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) event handlers on each element. Get the element's [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) `data-index` value and use that to change the background on all elements having the same value:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td[data-index]").forEach(di => {
  di.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`td[data-index="${di.dataset.index}"]`).forEach(
      dii => { dii.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEEEE"; }
    );
  });
  di.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`td[data-index="${di.dataset.index}"]`).forEach(
      dii => { dii.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";  }
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr> <td data-index="1">1</td> <td data-index="2">2</td> <td data-index="3">3</td> <td data-index="4">4</td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1">1</td> <td data-index="2">2</td> <td data-index="3">3</td> <td data-index="4">4</td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1">1</td> <td data-index="2">2</td> <td data-index="3">3</td> <td data-index="4">4</td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1">1</td> <td data-index="2">2</td> <td data-index="3">3</td> <td data-index="4">4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that with the `:has` selector (which is at the time of writing only supported by Chrome 105+ and Safari 15.4+), so not really useful right now.

Anyhow, with `:has` you could have a slector like `table:has([data-index="1"]:hover) [data-index="1"]`, which means, get the `table` elements that contains an element `[data-index="1"]` that is hovered, and select all descendance of that table that match `[data-index="1"]`

```css
table:has([data-index="1"]:hover) [data-index="1"] {
  background-color: red;
}

table:has([data-index="2"]:hover) [data-index="2"] {
  background-color: red;
}

table:has([data-index="3"]:hover) [data-index="3"] {
  background-color: red;
}

table:has([data-index="4"]:hover) [data-index="4"] {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td::before {
  content: attr(data-index);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Without the support of `:has` you need to use JavaScript.

For this purpose you can use event delegation, which has the advantage that the data attributes and number of elements can change without the need to update the listeners.

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('mouseover', (evt) => {
  if ( evt.target.matches('[data-index]') ) {
    table.dataset.hover = evt.target.dataset.index;
  }
})

table.addEventListener('mouseout', (evt) => {
  if ( evt.target.matches('[data-index]') ) {
    table.dataset.hover = 0;
  }
})
```

```css
[data-hover="1"] [data-index="1"] {
  background-color: red;
}

[data-hover="2"] [data-index="2"] {
  background-color: red;
}

[data-hover="3"] [data-index="3"] {
  background-color: red;
}

[data-hover="4"] [data-index="4"] {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td::before {
  content: attr(data-index);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
  <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
  <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
  <tr> <td data-index="1"></td> <td data-index="2"></td> <td data-index="3"></td> <td data-index="4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done like below.

```
td[data-index="1"]:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: To paraphrase the asker: "when I hover over one td element all the other td elements who share the data-index [to be styled]". This will only style the hovered element.

Comment: Right, I missed that part. Let me think and come back with something else. However, definitely made a correction to the way data-index was used in the css.